Как добавить собственные точки api в Medusa JS SDK
Я в админ панели Medusa js использую sdk типа
import { sdk } from "../../lib/config";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
        queryFn: () => sdk.admin.product.list(),
        queryKey: ["products"]
      })

Но я так же хочу использовать таким же образом собственный модуль - sdk.admin.recipe.list()
Есть ли такая возможность или нужно писать обычные fetch запросы ?
